# Does ‘more than’ need to comply with the object?

Tags: phrase-usage

Does ‘more than’ need to comply with the object?  That is, does ‘more than three people’ always mean ‘four or more *people*’?

I am specifically wondering if I can use ‘more than’ to compare numbers of different things.  For example, can I say "More than three people are dogs" to mean that there are four or more dogs in the room, which is more than three people?

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity.  I believe I have kept the main thrust of your original question while making it easier for native/fluent readers to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

*More than three people* always means *people*.

The quantifiers *three* or *four* or *more than three* modify the noun *people*.

If you want to compare numbers of two different things (nouns), you can say, for example,

*There were more dogs than people.*
or
*There were three people, and even more dogs.*

Those phrases have two different nouns, whose numbers are compared.

Comment: More than three beautiful dogs in the house always means beautiful dogs in the house?

Comment: What I wonder is when we talk about twice my dogs they don’t need to be my dogs. More than my dogs also don’t need to be my dogs?

Comment: Yes, if you start with *beautiful dogs*, that's your subject. You might say *She has twice my dogs*, to mean *she has twice as many dogs as I have*, but that is how it would be said.

Comment: O’Flaherty Then, twice my dogs in the house should be dogs in the house? I mean the prepositional phrase modifies the noun so twice my dogs should be in the house?

Comment: *Twice my dogs in the house* is a fragment, not a sentence, and it doesn't seem idiomatic to me, so I won't try to analyze it.

Comment: O’Flaherty You know back to beautiful dog, more than three beautiful dogs are dogs but don’t need to be my beautiful?

Comment: 284747, you started out talking about beautiful dogs. You haven't mentioned plain dogs or ugly dogs, so that's what your are talking about.

Comment: O’Flaherty Thank you.